# Python 2.7 IndentationError

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation, python-2.x, libtcod

I am getting an IndentationError when trying to run my program in a Python Interpreter:

```
 line 127
    global map
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I am using python version 2.7

What's wrong with the following code?:

```
def make_map():
global map
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot to linkl the code xD here it is:
http://pastebin.com/E9cd9KaB

Comment: You missed the link twice. Nice try. It seems on line 127, you're missing 4 spaces (or a tab) to indent your code and align it as Python expects

Comment: This should instead be a duplicate of [I'm getting an IndentationError (or a TabError). How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python expects 4 spaces or a tab to indent and align code - similar to Java expecting curly {} brackets are the start of a loop, method or class etc.

```
def some_function():
somecode
morecode
...
```

should be formatted as

```
def some_function():
    somecode
    morecode
    ...
```

It appears that your code throws an exception on line 127, so check this and indent the code as required.

```
def some_code():
    for i in range(1, some_value):
        some_method()

        if need_more_indent:
            indent_code()

        do_this_after_indent_code()

    this_runs_after_for_loop()

    return 'lol'
```