# How do you correctly handle a PUT request in a python 2.7 server

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a client app which is using a PUT request to 'PUT' a zip archive at a source URL.
I am trying to validate the content from the PUT request. My test framework is in python, so I am trying to start a basic python server to listen for PUT requests and write the file 'PUT' to disk.

I wanted to use the simpleHTTPServer, but it does not support PUT.

*python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9009
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 9009 ...
[23/Jan/2018 06:49:52] code 501, message Unsupported method ('PUT')
[23/Jan/2018 06:49:52] "PUT /a3866ad0-004c-11e8-99b0-ab49af452a48.zip HTTP/1.1" 501*

I figured I could write my own custom requestHandler class for the PUT and just write the content to disk based on its length, but the PUT no content-length header, so I can't do this either.

```
class SputHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
def do_PUT(self):
    print "headers"
    print self.headers
    print "---- done headers ----"
    length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
    with open("myTestZip.zip", "wb") as f:
        f.write(self.rfile.read(length))
```

However it seems the file is 'PUT' in multiple chunks, as there is no 'content-length' header and i see a 'transfer-encoding' header as 'chunked'.
I can see in the printed headers, the content-length doesn't exist.

> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
>   headers
>   host: myHostNameBlah:8000
>   content-type: application/zip
>   Connection: close
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> ---- done headers ----
>   Exception happened during processing of request from
>   ('clientIpAddress', 47362) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 290, in
>   _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 652, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
>       self.handle_one_request()   File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in handle_one_request
>       method()   File "tserver.py", line 10, in do_PUT
>       length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])   File "C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py", line 393, in **getitem**
>       return self.dict[name.lower()] KeyError: 'content-length'

Is there a simpleHTTPServer PUT handler implementation that will allow me to write the PUT zip archive to disk to act on later.
The solutions i have found are all using the content-length header, is there a way to write the contents to disk without this header?

Or is this an issue with the client? Is it required it sends a content-length header? My understanding is if the data is chunked, then the content-length header is not needed.

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: This might not answer your question however:
The defined function doesn't seem to be in the class
There is "indention" missing in the class definition
Maybe have a look here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405772/python-2-7-indentationerror#38405834rllib.request.Request)