# Machine Learning: how to find missing info

Tags: python

```
def process_text(title):
nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
clean_texts = [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english']
return clean_texts

  File "<ipython-input-34-7ad84bab21d6>", line 3
    nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I am new to machine learning and can someone tell me what is causing this problem

Comment: python uses indentation to create blocks of code. all the coide under def should be 4 spaces more to the right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 2.7 IndentationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405772/python-2-7-indentationerror)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Indentation is a way of telling the Python interpreter that a series of statements belong to a particular block of code, much like how other languages use {}.

```
def process_text(title):

    nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
    clean_texts = [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in 
        stopwords.words('english']

    return clean_texts
```